# math question/puzzle: Tokens Taken

Tags: probability, integers

Three bags each contain tokens. The green bag contains 22 round green tokens,
each with a different integer from 1 to 22. The red bag contains 15 triangular red
tokens, each with a different integer from 1 to 15. The blue bag contains 10
square blue tokens, each with a different integer from 1 to 10.

Any token in a specific bag has the same chance of being selected as any other
token from that same bag. There is a total of 22 × 15 × 10 = 3300 different
combinations of tokens created by selecting one token from each bag. Note that
selecting the 7 red token, the 5 blue token and 3 green token is different than
selecting the 5 red token, 7 blue token and the 3 green token. The order of
selection does not matter.

You select one token from each bag. What is the probability that two or more of the selected tokens have the number 5 on them?

Am I on the right track? Here is my work
[image]

Do we only have 8/3300 with 2 or more tokens with number 5? I feel like something is wrong, please help, thank you!

Comment: One mistake you were making is in counting the X only once. While I think your X indicates that it could be anything, you need to count options for the anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green bag has two tokens out of $22$ containing the digit $5$. The red bag has two out of $15$, and the blue bag has one out of ten.

Ways for all three tokens to contain a $5$: $2\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 4$.

Ways for green and red to contain a $5$, but not blue: $2\cdot 2\cdot (10-1) = 36$.

Ways for green and blue to contain a $5$, but not red: $2\cdot (15-2)\cdot 1 = 26$.

Ways for red and blue to contain a $5$, but not green: $(22-2)\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 40$.

Total: $\dfrac{4+36+26+40}{3300} = \dfrac{53}{1650}$

Comment: Great help, appreciated!